# Is the mean of predicted theta scores supposed to be 0?

Tags: item-response-theory

I predicted theta scores using a GPCM (based on 7-point attitude answers). I expected the mean of the predicted theta scores to be 0. However, it is not. Can anyone explain to me whether the mean of the scores is supposed to be 0?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

True is, that in order to make the GPCM identifiable, one needs to impose constraints -- among others on the location parameter. However, that does not necessarily mean a Zero-constraint on the location of the theta scores. The zero-constraint can be imposed on the sum of the itemparameters.

Even if the constraint is imposed on the person side, -- at least in the case of a marginal maximum likelihood estimation -- this constraint applies to the location parameter of the *prior distribution*; not on the posterior distribution and neither on the mean of the point estimates. In practice, both the center of the posterior distribution as well as the mean of the point estimates are sufficiently close to 0 if the constraint is applied on the person side.